# connection timeout after request is read in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

After continuous time of the endpoint we are getting the message connection timeout after request is read and esb will stop responding. we need to restart the wso2 services again.
i had increase the socket time out as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Time out in the esb is defined in three levels.
endpoint timeout < socket timeout < synapse timeout.check[1]

If you have defined enpoint timeout for your endpoint you can increase it up to the timeout value of socket timeout. and you can in crease the socket time out to the vlaue of synapse timeout. default synapse timeout is 2 minutes.So even you increase the endpoint timeout and socket time out to 2 minutes and you dont get any response form your backend service,Then you should check your backend service.

once timeout occurred that enpoint will be suspended to 30000ms .So any request to that endpoint within the suspension period will be ignored by esb. you can disable the suspension period as mention here [2]

Default keepalive property is enabled in the esb .But some firewalls will ignore keep alive packets form esb .So there will be a actual connection between esb and firewall .But connection form firewall to backend might be closed.In that case disabling the keepalive property will create new connection for each request[3] and backend will give the response.

1.http://soatutorials.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-configure-timeouts-in-wso2-esb.html
2.http://miyurudw.blogspot.com/2012/02/disable-suspension-of-wso2-esb-synapse.html
3.https://udaraliyanage.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/wso2-esb-keep-alive-property/